# MySQL 1 line comment - Is it possible string -''?

Tags: mysql, sql

My understanding, I know only `--` that is 1 line comment.

But `-''` also work like comment...

It is sample query.

```
select user()-'';
```

it return 0

why `-''` is working?

Comment: mysql convert user() and '' to numbers and returns result

Comment: It just looks like it works like a comment in this case. Add something else after it and you'll see.